# Can't configure filters with dictConfig

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-logging

I'm having trouble configuring filters in logging with `dictConfig`. this is the config dictionary I'm using

```
{ 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
  'filters': { 'request': { '()': <class 'applogging.filters.RequestFilter'>}},
  'formatters': { 'full': { 'format': '[%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(request_id)s] %(name)s[%(filename)s:%(module)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d]: %(message)s'},
                  'medium': { 'format': '[%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(request_id)s] %(name)s[%(module)s:%(lineno)d]: %(message)s'},
                  'short': { 'format': '[%(levelname)-8s] [%(request_id)s] TEST :%(name)s:%(lineno)d: %(message)s'}},
  'handlers': { 'default': { 'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                             'formatter': 'short',
                             'level': 'DEBUG'}},
  'loggers': { '': { 'filters': ['request'],
                     'handlers': ['default'],
                     'level': 'WARNING',
                     'propagate': True},
               'billing': { 'level': 'INFO'},
               'boto': { 'level': 'WARNING'},
               'boto3': { 'level': 'WARNING'},
               'botocore': { 'level': 'WARNING'},
               'shiphero.bulkship': { 'level': 'INFO'},
               'shiphero.core.product.uploader': { 'level': 'INFO'},
               'shiphero.inventory.uploader': { 'level': 'INFO'},
               'shiphero_app.core.inventory': { 'level': 'INFO'},
               'shiphero_app.core.order': { 'level': 'INFO'},
               'shiphero_app.core.rules.allocation': { 'level': 'DEBUG'},
               'shiphero_app.modules.queue_workers': { 'level': 'INFO'},
               'shiphero_app.modules.tasks': { 'level': 'INFO'},
               'shiphero_app.services.pending_shipments': { 'level': 'DEBUG'},
               'shiphero_app.services.returns': { 'level': 'INFO'},
               'shiphero_app.services.shipment': { 'level': 'DEBUG'}},
  'version': 1}
```

The `request` filter adds `record.request_id` to the log records as per https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#filters-contextual

```
class RequestFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if not request:
            return True

        record.url = request.url
        record.body = request.get_json()
        if 'request_id' not in g:
            g.request_id = uuid.uuid4()
        record.request_id = g.request_id
        return True
```

but the filter doesn't run, when I try to log something, it says: `KeyError: 'request_id'`

If I add this to the root of the config dictionary:

```
  'loggers': { '': { 'filters': ['request'],
               ....
  'root': {
      'filters': ['request'],
  }
```

or I use `'root': { 'filters': ['request']....` inside `'loggers'`, then the error disappears and the filter runs, but the format strings are ignored.

What am I missing?